# How do I modify the Joomla search plugin to search tables I have added to my database?

Tags: search, jquery-plugins, joomla

Most of my content is in a new table I have added to JOOMLA cms. I have to add a search plugin that can search this table.

Here is aq basic table search that I can't incorporate into a search plugin.

```
Select * FROM `jos_table` WHERE Abc = 'xyz'
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do not modify the existing Joomla search plugin; create a new one to sit alongside the other search plugins: http://docs.joomla.org/How_to_create_a_search_plugin

Comment: I looked at the Joomla documentation.  The problem is I still can't figure out where to type in my table query.

Comment: Towards the bottom of that example is where the query gets built.